# curl (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 20

Tags: node.js

When I use the following command

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" --data '{"peer" : "ws://localhost:6001"}' http://localhost:3001/addPeer
```

I get the following

```
curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is the first character  
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 20
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3001: Connection refused
```

I am on Windows. 
Nodejs version is 8.12.0 and npm version is 6.4.1

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try this:

```
curl.exe -H "Content-type:application/json" --data "{'peer' : 'ws://localhost:6001"}" http://localhost:3001/addPeer
```